# How to load result of a javascript function to a new tab

Tags: javascript, url, tabs

I've got a function that does Ajax to load certain html portion. Sometimes I need the result to be displayed in a separate window (or a tab if you will). When I include that function call in an anchor element's href attribute I can get that behavior:

```
   <a href="javascript:viewInternalDocument('AF7GH209')" target="_blank">Related document</>
```

But if I try to do it manually by calling window.open, I just get blank tab:

```
 window.open("javascript:viewInternalDocument('AF7GH209')","_blank");
```

In fact, the new tab opens even if I omit the `_blank` argument.

If you wonder what my `viewInternalDocument` function does, then here's the internals of it:

```
    function viewInternalDoc(docID) {
    var url = "/Cabinet/ViewInternalDocument";
    var args = { docID: docID};
    $.get(url, args, function (html) {
        $('#divContentHierarchy').html(html);
    }).fail(function () {
        alert('Error loading selected document')
    });
}
```

When I try `window.open('javascript:alert("Hello")')`, I can get the alert in a new tab (again, omitted the "_blank"). So what is the problem with not displaying the result of my function?

**EDIT:** I just realized that function does not work with the anchor element either. I somehow confused. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new window, get your content and then insert content into the window with jQuery:

```
  var w = window.open();
  $(w.document.body).html(viewInternalDocument('AF7GH209'));
```

or with vanillaJS:

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.body.innerHTML = viewInternalDocument('AF7GH209');
```